# Replace array symbol

Tags: php, json

I am submitting a JSON request to an API based on GO, which requires to send empty values as below snippet:

```
...
"Data": {
    "values": {}
},
...
```

I am converting a PHP array to JSON using json_enocde($mydata), which returns values as:

```
<?php
$mydata = array(
  'Data' => array(
          'values' => array()
       )
);
$mydata = json_encode($mydata);
//outputs
"Data": {
    "values": []
},
```

How can I get `{}` instead `[]` symbol. For now I am using below hack to replace empty array values symbol with `{}`.

```
$mydata = str_replace('[]','{}',$mydata);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[] - is an array, but {} - is an object, so change it:

```
<?php
$mydata = array(
  'Data' => array(
          'values' => new \stdClass()
       )
);
$mydata = json_encode($mydata);
echo $mydata;
```

output

```
{"Data":{"values":{}}}
```